# How to track unsaved changes in reactive forms ? How to prevent user from clicking buttons on the same page before saving?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a form using the reactive form approach, now I want to prevent the user from clicking on buttons if he has unsaved changes.

I tried using -

```js
if (this.exampleForm.dirty) {
    alert('Unsaved Changes');
} else {
   --proceed logic
}
```

But this always keeps the form dirty even when the user saves the unsaved changes.

Can anyone suggest to me a better way to achieve this?

Comment: do you call `this.createPrpjectDetailsForm.markAsPristine()` when the form has been saved ?

Comment: No @J.Loscos , do i have to ?

Comment: Thank you @J.Loscos . Learnt about pristine and used it . It worked . Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've said you're using the reactive form approach you can simply use `dirty`:

```
<div class="important" *ngIf="createPrpjectDetailsForm.dirty == true">Form changes need to be saved first before submitting order.</div>
<button type="button" *ngIf="createPrpjectDetailsForm.dirty == false">Submit</button>
```

And as L.Loscos has mentioned, mark the form as pristine on save. `this.createPrpjectDetailsForm.markAsPristine()`

Comment: Thank you . It worked . Learnt something new about Pristine today .